# css drop down list align img and text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I have a problem in my css that I can figure it out, I need to align the text and the img in my drop down list in the center.
The igm looks in center but the text is a bit lower. 
I want also to make the text a bit far from the img

Any help ?
This is what I get [image]
I deleted alot of source code CSS to be able to publish the auestion, I hope my issue is not in what I deleted.
HTML

```
    <section class="main">
        <div class="wrapper-demo">
            <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-2">
                <span>Deutsch</span>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/flags/flags_iso/32/de.png" >Deutsch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/flags/flags_iso/32/en.png" >English</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/flags/flags_iso/32/fr.png" >Fran&ccedil;ais</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/flags/flags_iso/32/es.png" >Español</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        ​</div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
/* DEMO 2 */

.wrapper-dropdown-2 {
    /* Size and position */
    position: relative; /* Enable absolute positionning for children and pseudo elements */
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 15px;

    /* Styles */
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 5px solid grey;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey transparent;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown {
  /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -5px;
    right: 0px;



    /* Hiding */
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    border-left: 5px solid;
    padding: 10px;

}


.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li i {
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
}




/* Active state */

.wrapper-dropdown-2.active:after {
    border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2.active .dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

/* No CSS3 support */

.no-opacity       .wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown {
    display: none;
    opacity: 1; /* If opacity support but no pointer-events support */
    pointer-events: auto; /* If pointer-events support but no pointer-events support */
}

.no-opacity       .wrapper-dropdown-2.active .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-2.active .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li a img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: You're the best man ;) it works. I thought the issue is in the text I was playing around dropdown li a. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can only answer, I do not have enough points to comment. It looks like your flag images have a bigger height than the text. Therefore this will increase the height of the div that contains the flag and the text.

```
[]
[]English
```

Above, the 4 square brackets represent the flag. This is what is happening. Whereas if they were the same size:

```
[]English
```

Comment: This have nothing to do, the img size has no relation with its alignment. Thank you anyway

Comment: If the flags and the text are in the same element (which they are) then the biggest 'item' will set the height. So if the flags height were 20px and the text size was 10px then div height will be 20px, therefore the text will be at the bottom of the div as it is in your original image. :)

Comment: @BradSutherland see the accepted answer. It is certainly possible to vertically align two inline block elements of different heights.

Comment: I see the answer, it is correct. Im just saying that without the vertical align, the problem was the flag setting the height. I just couldn't find the actual answer but thought my input may point in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown li a
{
display: inline-block;
line-height: 18px;
}
.dropdown li img
{
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. Code without explanation is not as helpful for future visitors.